# Is it possible to draw strings with custom paragraph styles in CATextLayer?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-animation, catextlayer

I want to draw a list like this:

```
 1. List item 1
 2. List item 2
 3. List item 3
```

Here is my code:

```
NSTextList *list = [[NSTextList alloc] initWithMarkerFormat:@"{decimal}" options:0];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paragraph setTextLists:[NSArray arrayWithObject:list]];
[list release];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:paragraph, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
NSString *string = @"List item 1\nList item 2\nList item 3"
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes] autorelease];
[paragraph release];
```

Then I set the attrString to the string property of CATextLayer, but paragph style isn't applied to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can create NSAttributedString by using either `initWithHTML*` or `initWithRTF*` method.
If you want to create list programmatically, you can use NSTextTab in tandem with NSTextList. But you have to manually format string:

```
NSTextList *list = [[NSTextList alloc] initWithMarkerFormat:@"square" options:0];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paragraph setTextLists:[NSArray arrayWithObject:list]];
NSTextTab *t1 = [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:0 location:11.0f];
NSTextTab *t2 = [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:0 location:36.0f];
[paragraph setTabStops:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:t1, t2, nil]];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:paragraph, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
NSString *string = @"\t▪\tList item 1\n\t▪\tList item 2\n\t▪\tList item 3";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes] autorelease];
[paragraph release];
[list release];
[t1 release];
[t2 release];
```